# Trying to clean up a comment thread about my wrong assumption and all my flags were declined

Tags: discussion, status-completed, comments, declined-flags, comment-flags

I made a mistake in a comment.  This lead to a long chain of comments from me and several other users.  Once I finally realized what happened I retracted my comments and flag the ones that related to it as no longer needed.  Some of the comments were deleted, not sure if a mod did that or the other user self cleaned them up, but a lot of the others are still there and all my flags were declined.

What is going on here?  Shouldn't we be cleaning up the comments when they are no longer needed, especially since the comment that started it all was wrong?  If that's the case can I get these flags disputed instead and we can get the remaining comment deleted?  The last four comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53745912/is-there-any-need-to-make-an-integer-literal-unsigned?noredirect=1#comment94345649_53745912) all stem from my comment and are out of place without the previous comments and should be deleted IMHO.

Comment: Gotta be careful; if it looks like you're just trying to silence someone, mods ain't gonna be too accommodating.

Comment: @Shog9 Should I have mod flagged instead?  I went with comment flags because I know those get cleaned up a lot faster.

Comment: I usually use a custom mod flag on the post in situations like this so I can specify why they are no longer needed, and specify the comments in need of deletion. Something like "The discussion in the comments here between me and X is no longer needed because the confusion has been resolved and all relevant clarifications have resulted in edits to the post."